# Applying function to the subsequent rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the distance and the average speed of movements for the provided list of locations.

The datafrane looks as follows:

```
                             GpsLatitude  GpsLongitude  TotalWorkingHours
DateTime                                                               
2018-11-16 14:30:23+00:00    46.022116     20.093600                NaN
2018-11-16 14:30:31+00:00    46.022109     20.093605             359.53
2018-11-16 14:30:41+00:00    46.022103     20.093602             359.53
2018-11-16 14:37:21+00:00    46.022124     20.093568             359.53
2018-11-16 14:37:31+00:00    46.022123     20.093566             359.53
```

The function for calculating the distance is the following:

```
def get_distance_from_geopoints(latlng1, latlng2):
    lat1, lng1 = latlng1
    lat2, lng2 = latlng2
    R = 6373.0
    dlng = lng2 - lng1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlng / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c * 1000
    return distance
```

To create a dataframe with rows that contain starting position, ending position, distance, and average speed, I wrote the following:

```
df_rolling = df.rolling(window=2)
df_activity['distance_traveled'] = df_rolling.apply(lambda x: get_distance_from_geopoints((x[0]['GpsLatitude'], x[0]['GpsLongitude']), (x[1]['GpsLatitude'], x[1]['GpsLongitude'])), axis=1)
df_activity['time_difference_h'] = df_rolling['TotalWorkingHours'].apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
df_activity['GpsLatitudeStart'] = df_rolling['GpsLatitude'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df_activity['GpsLongitudeStart'] = df_rolling['GpsLongitude'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df_activity['GpsLatitudeEnd'] = df_rolling['GpsLatitude'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df_activity['GpsLongitudeEnd'] = df_rolling['GpsLongitude'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df_activity['average_speed_kmh'] = df_serial.apply(lambda x: x['distance_traveled']/x['time_difference_h'])
```

Running the above, I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>
> ----> 1 df.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: get_distance_from_geopoints((x[0].GpsLatitude, x[0].GpsLongitude),
> (x[1].GpsLatitude, x[1].GpsLongitude)), axis=1)
>
> TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Also, applying a rolling window for every transformation, I believe is not optimal in terms of execution time so I am trying to find an alternative to apply rolling window once to get an intermediate transformation and then use that to extract starting point, ending point, calculate the time and distance difference and the average speed.

Comment: Rolling doesn't natively support processing multiple columns at a time. (much like aggregate). `rolling` is, however, an iterable which you could try processing as a loop or comprehension.

Comment: Use `shift` instead.   df and df.shift(-1) to bring next row up to line up with current row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `shift` move the next row up to current row for alignment and calculations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(10)})

df['col1'] + df['col1'].shift(-1).fillna(0)*10
```

Output:

```
   col1  nextSum
0     0     10.0
1     1     21.0
2     2     32.0
3     3     43.0
4     4     54.0
5     5     65.0
6     6     76.0
7     7     87.0
8     8     98.0
9     9      9.0
```